# Database state between multiple applications

Tags: c++, sql-server, performance, transactions

I have a game server that uses a SQL database to store/retrieve player data. The game server has a queue of pending database requests/queries to avoid blocking the network thread poll. If there's too many players playing, the database gets stressed and begins slowing down queries.

If I have multiple servers running, my fear is that one player could disconnect, and before its information gets saved to the database, the same player connects to another game server (multiple rooms) and gets the old information loaded (making him lose progress in the game).

I was wondering if there's any way to manage this type of synchronization between multiple application instances (game servers).

I thought about transactions, but that can still cause problems if the queue isn't getting dequeued fast enough (queries pending on the server memory - not on database server).

Making a "database server" in which all gameservers connects and requests database operations (thus avoiding multiple queues) is **not an option**.

Assume that database is perfectly optimized and the solutions must be made on the application itself.

What are my options here?

Comment: You're essentially asking, how to achieve [consitency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consistency_model) in a distributed system.

Comment: @user2079303 any known solutions?

Comment: Many, I would expect. I haven't studied it, but it's a vast subject. As a naïve solution, my first attempt would be to store a timestamp whenever player data is modifier. And whenever a player connects, ask all databases whether they have a newer timestamp, and synchronize if needed. This does greatly slow down the initial connect time and also requires the clocks of the servers to be synchronized.

Comment: I'm thinking about a message queue to replicate information about "pending tasks" between the running servers and wait for completion if there's something locking up an account.

Answer (score 0):

When a player connects, create an "open" record in the database.   When he disconnects, create a "close" record.

When a player re-connects, don't allow a new "open" record to be created until all existing "open" records have a matching "close" record.

Comment: If server crashes for some reason or lose database connectivity, accounts will be locked up.

Comment: Well, yeah, I'm assuming that in order to play the game you need a working server and a connection to the database.

Comment: I'll think about it. Still feels there's something better that can be done.